# requestAction performance in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In every documentation of CakePHP it is written that requestAction decreases performance of the CakePHP. It is always reccomended to use controller action and get results with the view file. But sometimes I really need requestAction.

[CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction):

> If used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance. It
>   is rarely appropriate to use in a controller or model.

What processes make reuqestAction to decrease performance.

What should one do, to prevent performance loss of requestAction ?
Adding thing like that ?

`$this->autoRender = false`
to controller action,

```
function beforeFilter() {
  if ( $this->params['action'] == "myaction" ) { return; }
}
```

to controller class

Comment: `requestAction` gets a bum rap, but it's really not *that* bad, as much of the request time is talking to the server and interpreting in the browser, which isn't done since it's technically in the same HTTP request. Try some quick benchmarking for yourself to see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by looking at [**how it is written**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2/lib/Cake/Core/Object.php#L66).

As I read it, it would each time it would re-parse the URL (in [`Router::normalize()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php#L1022)), creates new `CakeRequest` instance (which [always loads configuration](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2/lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php#L261)) and then try to [`Dispatcher::dispatch()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L139).

P.S. .. it's a giant mess, i don't even see at which point cache there is used .. if ever.

Answer (score 1):

Basically requestAction() hits your action with additional page request. Moreover the requestAction() treats the url differently, because it will return data other than string. So at controller you need to check the type of return request first.

Here is a good article about [requestAction()](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/reducing-requestaction-use-in-your-cakephp-sites-with-fat-models)

Answer (score 1):

(After 1,5 years of CakePHP experience) I can say that if there is a requestAction, there exists a refactor need. In the first months I was adding too much requestActions. After getting information that requestAction decreases performance I didn't add any more.

With months pass I removed nearly every requestAction from my codes. In a big code repository we only have 3-4 requestActions and they only be hitten once a day. If you use requestAction, you are missing valuable information from the controller layer to view layer. Please rethink the usage.